# ¿Cómo filtrar por horas, minutos y segundos?

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, odoo10

Tengo un filtro en el que estoy intentando filtrar un hora pasada respecto de la actual pero no me funciona.

**views.xml**

```
<filter name="fecha_hora" string="1 hour" domain="[('fecha_hora', '&gt;',      ((context_today()-datetime.timedelta(hours=1).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d%%H:%%M:%%S')),('fecha_hora', '&lt;', (context_today()+datetime.timedelta(hours=1).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d%%H:%%M:%%S'))]"/>
```

**Odoo Odoo Client Error**

```
Error: Error evaluando los criterios de búsqueda: 
{"code":400,"message":"Error de evaluación","data":{"type":"local_exception","debug":"Fallo de la evaluación local\nExpected \")\", got \"]\"\n\n{\"domains\":[[],\"[('fecha_hora', '>', (((context_today()-datetime.timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')),('fecha_hora', '<', ((context_today()+datetime.timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S'))))]\"],\"contexts\":[{\"lang\":\"es_ES\",\"tz\":false,\"uid\":1,\"params\":{\"action\":645}},{}],\"group_by_seq\":[]}"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que te devuelve es debido a los paréntesis, debes englobar la operación de las fechas entre paréntesis para luego aplicar el formateo.

```
( context_today()-datetime.timedelta(hours=1) ).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d%%H:%%M:%%S')
```

A parte, creo recordad que context_today devuelve un datetime.date, por lo que no serviría restarle una hora.

Yo probaría con

```
( datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(hours=1) ).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d%%H:%%M:%%S')
```

Saludos